# RAM Not Adding Up In Windows 10 (Nonpaged / Poolmon OK)

Tags: windows-10, memory

like many others here, I noticed that the total RAM my processes are using (around 6 GB) does not add up to the total RAM used (around 11 GB). I downloaded WDK and ran poolmon, and nothing really big came up; the nonpaged pool amount - 525 MB does not seem very high.

The system is running Windows 10 with 16 GB physical memory (2 8 GB cards - I recently installed the second one).

Here are some screenshots of Task Manager, Resource Monitor, and Poolmon. Would be grateful for any pointers to what the problem may be.

[image: Processes Tab]
[image: Performance Tab]
[image: Poolmon]
[image: Resource Monitor]

Here is a screenshot showing the reveal arrows on Firefox and Android Studio being expanded, yet the 'missing' RAM is nowhere to be found
[image: Reveal Arrows]

Comment: What practical problem are you trying to solve? You'll probably find the 'missing' RAM in the reveal arrows on firefox & possibly android studio, but I don't see any actual problem that needs solving.

Comment: The problem is that my computer freezes due to low available RAM when the load is higher. Right now it is only using 11 / 16 GB, but if I open more programs the RAM used gets to 16 GB and the computer freezes - even though adding up each program's individual memory used comes out to far less. I added a screenshot with the arrows next to Firefox & Android Studio expanded. There is no 'missing' RAM for those.

Comment: There are so many posts on this subject on our site. Why another one?

Comment: Because the frequently suggested solution doesn't work.

Comment: This is a pretty clear case of someone showing that poolmon _doesn't report_ what all the answers say it should be reporting, making it worth getting a real answer, even today. I'm currently looking at a machine that has 64GB installed, of which 40GB is in use. By nothing, apparently. Because not even the numbers reported by poolmon add up to anywhere near that, and none of the other answers were any use to me, either.